# React redux doesn't return current state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, thunk

I have a problem with redux thunk in react. In the thunk file, I use to dispatch actions and change isSuccess and isLoading flag from the reducer, but in the component, after the API call, I get the previous value of these instead of the current ones.

**components.jsx**

```js
 await addClient(valueToSubmit, employee.tenantId).then((response) => {
    if (isSuccess) {
      showToast(toastTypes.SUCCESS, translate("client_add_success"));
      resetForm();
      setSubmitting(false);
      toggleModal();
      setFieldsWithError([]);
    } else {
      showToast(
        toastTypes.ERROR,
        message.debugMessage?.includes("exist")
          ? translate("client_exist_error")
          : translate("client_add_error")
      );
      setFieldsWithError(message.payload);
    }
  });
```

**thunk.js**

```js
export const addClient = (data, tenant) => async (dispatch) => {
  const tenantId = tenant?.replace(/['"]+/g, "");
  dispatch(requestAddClient());

  return await api(
    "post",
    apiUrl,
    data,
    tenant ? { "tenant-uuid": tenantId } : {},
    false
  )
    .then((response) => {
      return dispatch(receiveAddClient(response.data.payload));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return dispatch(errorAddClient(err.response));
    });
};
```

**actions.js**

```js
export const requestAddClient = () => {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_ADD_CLIENT,
  };
};

export const receiveAddClient = (client) => {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_ADD_CLIENT,
    client: client,
  };
};

export const errorAddClient = (message) => {
  return {
    type: ERROR_ADD_CLIENT,
    message,
  };
};
```

**reducer.js**

```js
case REQUEST_ADD_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        client: {},
        isSuccess: false,
        isLoading: true,
      };

    case RECEIVE_ADD_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        client: action.client,
        clients: [...state.clients, action.client],
        isSuccess: true,
        isLoading: false,
      };

    case ERROR_ADD_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        client: {},
        message: action.message.data,
        isSuccess: false,
        isLoading: false,
      };
```

and I can't resolve this problem. If anybody knows the reason, please tell me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In addClient thunk you can rethrow in catch

```
.catch((err) => {
  dispatch(errorAddClient(err.response));
  return Promise.reject(err.response.data)
});
```

In your component you can do:

```
await addClient(valueToSubmit, employee.tenantId).then(
  (response) => {
    showToast(
      toastTypes.SUCCESS,
      translate('client_add_success')
    );
    resetForm();
    setSubmitting(false);
    toggleModal();
    setFieldsWithError([]);
  },
  (message) => {
    //promise was rejected
    showToast(
      toastTypes.ERROR,
      message.debugMessage?.includes('exist')
        ? translate('client_exist_error')
        : translate('client_add_error')
    );
    setFieldsWithError(message.payload);
  }
);
```

Another (better) way to do it is to use `useEffect` checking the status of the request from the state using `useSelector` and triggering what needs to be done based on that value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I haven't understood at all what I have to do. What I have to do in the useEffect ?